# Android - Let user drag/move an image around

Tags: java, android

I have looked around the net and stackover flow and seen some answers on how to create a motionevent/drag for an image in my app.

So far I have implemented the following:

```
private void dragAndDrop(){

    image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) image
                    .getLayoutParams();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                    int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                    if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                        x_cord = windowwidth;
                    }
                    if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                        y_cord = windowheight;
                    }

                    layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                    layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - 75;

                    image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Now this works to an extent, but every time I click on the image, the image will jump below about a few centimetres below my finger, I am not sure why

But I can move the image around just fine.
But my question is, is this now the updated way to do it? Have I missed an easy to use class to let the user move the image around?

Thanks

Comment: Due to these two lines: `layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord - 25; layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - 75;`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's basically asking for debugging/fixing of some code found somewhere on the internet.

Comment: it is not for debugging, the question is asking if someone knows a good/latest way to implement a way to let users move an image around @Shark

Comment: but the answer you gave has helped me resolve the issue, thanks for that

Comment: You're welcome.